# My CSS file not working, I couldn't make it worked

Tags: html, css

i'm very beginner of these things, the css is working on here but not in my laptop. these are all in the same folder but i couldn't got the problem.

```css
Selector {
 Property: value;
}

h1 {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>The Shippy!</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
 <body>
  <section>
  <h1>The Shippy</h1>
  <h4>Registration Form</h4>
  </section>
  <form> 
   Firm Name: <input type="text" required name="Firm"><br>
   Password:  <input type="Password" required name="Pass" minlength="6" maxlength="12"><br>   
   E-Mail: <input type="email" name="E-Mail"><br><br>
   Sector: <br>
   <input type="radio" name="Sector">Ship Supply<br>
   <input type="radio" name="Sector">Purchasing<br>
   <input type="radio" name="Sector">Crew Management<br>
   <input type="radio" name="Sector">Shipbreaking<br><br>
   Country:<br>
   <select>
    <option value="Turkey" name="Turkey">Turkey</option>
    <option value="Greece" name="Turkey">Greece</option>
   </select><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Register!" >
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a picture showing your folder structure?

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any CSS warnings. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource `style.css` _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? Inspect the elements to see which rules are applied.

Comment: @shippy is your CSS file named "style.css"? What is not working as expected? Try updating the question to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I will help you out with little changes that you were looking.

First, the line in HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Here, the href means the link to your external style sheet. The name of your external stylesheet is style.css . You have to refer it properly in **href** tag. So you can refer it two ways: 1) Relative Path (e.g: ~/YourForlderName/style.css ) and 2) Absolute Path (e.g: YourRootFolder/YourFileName/YourFolderName/style.css)

This can be written as follows:
**1) Using Relative Path**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Images/style.css">
```

**2) Using Absolute Path**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Project/Images/style.css">
```

Now, talking about your small project.

**This is external CSS. That is style.css followed by your HTML.**

```css
h1 {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>The Shippy!</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
 <body>
  <section>
  <h1>The Shippy</h1>
  <h4>Registration Form</h4>
  </section>
  <form> 
    <table>
       <tr>
       <td>First Name:</td>
       <td><input type="text" required name="Firm"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Password:</td>
       <td><input type="Password" required name="Pass" minlength="6" maxlength="12"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Email:</td>
       <td><input type="email" name="E-Mail"></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
   
   <br>
   <b>Sector:</b> <br>
   <input type="radio" name="Sector">Ship Supply<br>
   <input type="radio" name="Sector">Purchasing<br>
   <input type="radio" name="Sector">Crew Management<br>
   <input type="radio" name="Sector">Shipbreaking<br><br>
   
      <b>Country:</b><br>
   <select>
    <option value="Turkey" name="Turkey">Turkey</option>
    <option value="Greece" name="Turkey">Greece</option>
   </select><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Register!" >
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**FURTHER EXPLANATION ABOUT TABLE AND ITS RELATED TAGS:**

Notice that I have used a  tag align your labels and textboxes in a proper format. The **tr** tag means **TableRow**, and **td** means **TableData**. The **Td** tag divides row into particular number of column.

Hope this helps. And happy programming! :)